# Can all functions be written in the form $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac {x^i}{g(i)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)$ be any function. Can it be written in the form $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac {x^i}{g(i)}$ for some function $g(i)$? I believe it is true, but I have no means of explicitly proving it. I'm trying to dip my toes into the concepts of real analysis and figured this might be a good statement for me to try to prove.

I believe that the Taylor Series does have such a theorem stating this to be true, but I'm curious how one might *prove* it.

Comment: What about $f\equiv 0?$

Comment: What sort of function is $f$?  A function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?  Do you make any assumptions like continuity?

Comment: If you don't assume $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or something similar, what would $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac {x^i}{g(i)}$ even mean?  What does $x^i$ mean, if $x$ is not a number?

Comment: A function is just anything that takes elements of one set and outputs elements of another set.  The sets don't have to have anything to do with numbers.

Comment: Not all functions have a Taylor series representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I assume you mean for $f$ to be a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.]

No, almost all functions *cannot* be written in this form.  The easiest way to see this is by just counting.  Your $g$ is a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, so there are only $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$ such functions.  On the other hand, there are $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|=(2^{\aleph_0})^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Since $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>2^{\aleph_0}$, this means not all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can come from a function $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ in the way you describe (or in any other single way).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there exists a function $g$ such that
$$ f(x) \doteq \sin(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{g(n)} $$

Then $ f(0) = 0 = \sin(0) = \frac{1}{g(0)} $ which would imply $ 0 = 1 $.

Therefore, this is not true for arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Typhon It means that $f$ is equal by **definition** to the expression that follows next. This is kinda subtle and a bit of preciosity of mine, but we can define two functions with same domain by different expressions and yet they might be equal everywhere.